# Why is a function declaration not a statement while a variable declaration is

Tags: javascript

It seems like a stupid question but I really can't wrap my head around it. I began to wonder this when I was thinking of why there is a semicolon after variable declaration but not function declaration. So does that mean a function declaration is an expression?

And what is the official meaning for statement? I've been finding the answer saying that a statement is a "command" that tells computer what to do, but isn't a function declaration telling the computer what to do? Does it have something to do with when it's get loaded when executing the code?

Comment: See [the language spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12) for a definition of statement.

Comment: named function statements are (basically) converted to top-of-program var assignments to function expressions of the same name. if you can assign something to a var, it's an expression, it that errors, it's a statement (in general). also, statements generally affect the flow, expressions generally don't.

Comment: @dandavis: [named function statement???](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-statements)

Comment: function gt(n){return n>this;} is a statement, gt=function(n){return n>this;}; is an expression. both define functions. OOP'rs often don't like the statement form, preferring methods or expressions.

Comment: @dandavis: No, `function gt(n){return n>this;} ` is not a statement. See my answer. We have *function declarations* and *function expressions*. The latter can exist in a *named* and *anonymous* form. Function declarations always need a name. This might sound like splitting hairs, but terminology is important (hello [JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)!).

Comment: @FelixKling:Why does MDN put such constructs under /Statements/function/ in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function ? i've been calling them statements the whole time, so i'm interested in the distinction you're drawing, and why it's important...

Comment: @dandavis: For "simplicity" maybe (we should fix that)? I updated my answer with a bit more information, but tl;dr: If function declarations are statements, what happens when they are defined inside an `if...else` statement (remember hoisting)? See my answer. Most of the time it's probably not important to know that there is a difference, but we want to be correct, don't we? :)

Comment: @FelixKling: well, that's a gotcha with using function statements in blocks in a language without real blocks, but i;m not convinced that demands re-classification. if there is strong utility in drawing a distinction it's worthwhile, but if the distinction relates only to side-effects and internals on the spec's hypothetical reference implementation, it likely confounds user-land factoring more than it enlightens. i respect your insight, and i don't disagree, but after all this is JS, and so if it quacks and paddles, more people will grok "function statement" than more precise alternatives.

Comment: @dandavis: That's why it's good to just say function "declaration" ;)

Comment: that's good insight about hoisting. terms are widely used in existing literature, for example: "A function expression is very similar to and has almost the same syntax as a function statement (see function statement for details). The main difference between a function expression and a function statement is the function name, which can be omtted in function expressions to create anonymous functions." from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function . i dunno if it's better to be right, precise, or instructional, but that's another topic... darn js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I began to wonder this when I was thinking of why there is a semicolon after variable declaration but not function declaration

[Not every statement ends with a semicolon](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12).

Examples of statements with trailing semicolon:

- Variable declaration: `var foo = <expression>;`
- Expression statement: `<expression>;`
- Do while loop: `do <statement> while (<expression>);`

Examples without trailing semicolons:

- If statement: `if (<expression>) <statement>`
- Try catch statement: `try <block> catch (<identifier>) <block>`
- For loop: `for (...) <statement>`
- Block statement: `{ <statement list> }`

> So does that mean a function declaration is an expression?

No, it's more complicated than that. Function declarations are **not** statements. They are not expressions either, they are [**source elements**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.5). Statements and function declarations are both source elements. ******

---

> And what is the official meaning for statement?

I can't tell you the official definition, but in the context of JS I would say something like "it's an instruction that does not produce an assignable result/value". Expressions on the other hand produce a result that can be used in other expressions.

---

****** Good to know, but a bit off-topic: Since function declarations are not statements, they are technically not allowed to be used inside blocks. This becomes even more apparent if we also consider *hoisting*. This example should throw a syntax error in every browser, but unfortunately it doesn't.

```
if (true) {
  function foo() { alert('foo'); }
} else {
  function foo() { alert('bar'); }
}
foo();
```

This leads to different behaviors in different browser. While Chrome will show `bar`, Firefox will show `foo`. Chrome just hoists both function declarations, and the second overrides the first one. Firefox interprets both declarations as something like a *function expression*.

[Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/P5BQK/) in different browsers.

Comment: You only forget the completions statements (`break`/`continue`/`return`/`throw`), the empty statement and the `debugger;` statement :-)

Comment: @Bergi: There are more than I thought :)

Comment: Honestly, I would never have thought of the `do while` loop; I always omit that one. ASI FTW!

Comment: You should do that again. I just found the following in the spec: "*The result of evaluating a Statement is always a Completion value.*" Even though that's internal of course, it might be useful for further explanation of what they do

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, but you can't use that in code (not assignable). I considered it to be more like the ReferenceType, it's just internal to the specification. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A variable declaration can have side-effects (eg, `var x = alert(42);`).

A function declaration cannot.